# SSIS How to get part of a string by separator

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I need an SSIS expression to get the left part of a string before the separator, and then put the new string in a new column. I checked in derived column, it seems no such expressions. `Substring` could only return string part with fixed length.

For example, with separator string `-` :

```
Art-Reading                Should return Art
Art-Writing                Should return Art
Science-chemistry          Should return Science
```

P.S. 
I knew this could be done in MySQL with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`, but I'm looking for an equivalent in SSIS, or at least in SQL Server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with SubString in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324590/help-with-substring-in-ssis)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

of course you can:

[image]

just configure your derived columns like this:

[image]

Here is the expression to make your life easier:

```
SUBSTRING(name,1,FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1)
```

FYI, the second "1" means to get the first occurrence of the string "-"

EDIT:
expression to deal with string without "-"

```
FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) != 0 ? (SUBSTRING(name,1,FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1)) : name
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer!! However, some values of the "name" column do not have a seperator and in this case,  I wish the "new_name" column will be the same as "name". E.g. one of the name is "Science", and the new_name would just be "Science".  So the whole process would be like this: if name has a seperator, then use the solution, else, copy from name to new_name

Comment: that can easily be solved with a conditional expression. See my edit!

Answer (score 31):

Better late than never, but I wanted to do this too and found this.

```
TOKEN(character_expression, delimiter_string, occurrence)

TOKEN("a little white dog"," ",2)
```

returns little the source is below

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213216.aspx

Comment: This is probably the best answer here.

Comment: I have been looking for this forever!! Best answer

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the length to copy in the `SUBSTRING` function and check for the location of the  dash using `CHARINDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@sString, 1, CHARINDEX('-',@sString) - 1)
```

For the SSIS expression it is pretty much the same code:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::String], 1, FINDSTRING(@[User::String], "-", 1)-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

if SUBSTRING length param returns -1 then it results in error,
"The length -1 is not valid for function "SUBSTRING". The length parameter cannot be negative. Change the length parameter to zero or a positive value."