# SSIS migration to Dynamics CRM 2016 (Kingsway soft/visual studio)

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, sql-server-data-tools, data-migration, kingswaysoft

I am currently migrating some data from a holding database to dynamics CRM using SSIS/SSDT with Kingswaysoft plug in [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw6gK.png). 
I currently have a field which stores the value as one line however I require the fields to be split up and migrated to the other three fields as well as leaving the value in the mapped field.

So for example:
Storing Database (has data like this)
FIELD A:
ABC-123-321

I require the following once migrated to Dynamics CRM
FIELD A:
abc-123-321
FIELD B
ABC
FIELD C
123
FIELD D
321
So once there is a hyphen It should go the relevant field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve with the following expression.

```
SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME,1,FINDSTRING(FIELDNAME,"-",1) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a derived column transformation *before* the Kingswaysoft destination, this will allow you to split the column into three before mapping the derived column outputs into the CRM inputs. As long as you specify "add as new column" in the derived column transformation, the original will still be available in the dataflow for mapping.

Comment: Any idea on how the formula will look like?

Comment: I imagine it will use SUBSTRING. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137541.aspx for details.

Comment: Been looking at SUB STRING formula, having difficulties in creating the expression to separate each of the dashes as there are 3 dashes. example 123-abc-321 how would u look to

Comment: write a expression for that.

Comment: You need to find the "-" using FindString, then start (or finish) the substrings there as appropriate. There is a similar example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324590/help-with-substring-in-ssis

Comment: SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME,1,FINDSTRING(FIELDNAME,"-",1) - 1)