# SSIS Splitting a Full Name and ID Number

Tags: ssis, substring

I'm reading data through an excel source and trying to split a column that combines a members name along with their ID number.  I've successfully split the last name and the ID number, but I'm stuck with splitting the first name.

I've always taken the trial and error approach when it came to the substring function in SSIS plugging and playing answers from various SO posts and modifying them until I get the results, but I've been stuck with this problem for a while, hopefully someone can help.

So, in excel the column is set like so:

`"LNAME, FNAME M
H1112223334"`

To split the last name I have this:

```html
FINDSTRING([Member Detail],",",1) != 0 ? (SUBSTRING([Member Detail],1,FINDSTRING([Member Detail],",",1) - 1)) : [Member Detail]
```

the ID number is this:

```html
LTRIM(REVERSE(REVERSE(RIGHT(TRIM([Member Detail]),12))))
```

for the first name I currently have this:

```html
FINDSTRING([Member Detail],",",1) != 0 ? (SUBSTRING([Member Detail],10,FINDSTRING([Member Detail],",",1))) : [Member Detail]
```

which in the end gives me this as the results for the first name column:

`, FNAME M
H`

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get the string between the comma+space, and the next space.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yep, that's where the first name is.  I just needed help extracting it.

Comment: Why?   You seem to know how FindString and SubString work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with SubString in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324590/help-with-substring-in-ssis)

Comment: @TabAlleman If I knew how the functions worked, I wouldn't have asked the question. Thanks for your help though.